# clang ignoring attribute noinline

Tags: c++, clang, inline

I expected `__attribute__((noinline))`, when added to a function, to make sure that that function gets emitted. This works with gcc, but clang still seems to inline it.

Here is an example, which you can also [open on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/QMTL8f):

```
namespace {

__attribute__((noinline))
int inner_noinline() {
    return 3;
}

int inner_inline() {
    return 4;
}

int outer() {
    return inner_noinline() + inner_inline();
}

}

int main() {
    return outer();
}
```

When build with `-O3`, gcc emits `inner_noinline`, but not `inner_inline`:

```
(anonymous namespace)::inner_noinline():
        mov     eax, 3
        ret
main:
        call    (anonymous namespace)::inner_noinline()
        add     eax, 4
        ret
```

Clang insists on inlining it:

```
main: # @main
  mov eax, 7
  ret
```

If adding a parameter to the functions and letting them perform some trivial work, clang respects the noinline attribute: https://godbolt.org/z/NNSVab

Shouldn't noinline be independent of how complex the function is? What am I missing?

Comment: Does clang support `noinline` attribute?

Comment: It doesn't have its own category in the [list of attributes](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html), but if you search for noinline there, you will find it mentioned several times.

Comment: Also, looking at the version with parameters, if I remove it there, both functions are inlined. So clang seems to at least know it.

Comment: related: https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/3409

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`__attribute__((noinline))` prevents the compiler from inlining the function. It doesn't prevent it from doing constant folding. In this case, the compiler was able to recognize that there was no need to call `inner_noinline`, either as an inline insertion or an out-of-line call. It could just replace the function call with the constant `3`.

It sounds like you want to use the `optnone` attribute instead, to prevent the compiler from applying even the most obvious of optimizations (as this one is).

Comment: This, together with @YSC's comment, makes sense. It's interesting that clang and gcc seem to have different opinion of what constitutes inlining.